# Pasar una variable manipulada en Javascript a Java

Tags: javascript, java, zk

Dentro de mi aplicación, tengo un botón que abre una ventana modal y almaceno la respuesta de esta, tal que así.

```
function lanzarPeticionDependiente(aplicacion, operacion, parametros){
            var sFeatures = 'dialogHeight: 1200px; dialogWidth: 1000px; dialogTop: 150px; dialogLeft: 150px';
            var resultado=lanzarPeticion(aplicacion, operacion, parametros, false, '',sFeatures);}
```

lanzar peticion es simplemente una función que en función de los parámetros pasados decide si abre la aplicación en una ventana modal, nueva pestaña o en un iframe.En este caso ventana modal.

Al cerrarse la variable resultado tiene almacenado un XML. Ese xml querría manipularlo desde una clase Java, pero al ejecutar las funciones javascript con `Client.evalJavaScript()` pues no puedo hacer una función con el xml en un return y ya manipularlo.

Uso el framework ZK por si sirve de ayuda.